# Executed Bash script not reading a file if cwd is elsewhere

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I have a script in `home/me/bin` with an alias in my `.bashrc` which reads a file `xs.txt` also in `home/me/bin`. I want the script to count the lines of the contents of `xs.txt`; however, if I run my alias from another folder --- say, `Desktop` --- xs.txt is not found:

```
num_comps=$(wc -l < xs.txt)
```

With the error message:

```
home/me/bin/upper: line 20: xs.txt: No such file or directory.
sed: can't read xs.txt: No such file or directory
```

How can I format this line so that no matter which cwd I am in, I can always read from `xs.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer with post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200811/bash-read-from-file-in-the-same-directory-as-the-script-file

What I forgot was that a new shell session was called from cwd, so I had to cd into where xs.txt was located. A simple:

```
TARGET = /home/me/bin
cd $TARGET
```

And the script works right as rain.

Comment: Note that assignments in shell scripts can not have spaces around the `=`.  Your code, as currently written, would likely fail with a "command not found" error.